# Why after entering login route i get POST submit request instantly?

Tags: python, flask, http-post, flask-wtforms

I've created "LoginForm" that inherits from FlaskForm and when i've tried to enter Login site it immediately enters validate_on_submit() or is_Submitted() method without doing anything on site. It looks like site is generating POST request, but i don't know why.

Firstly i've checked validate_on_submit() then i've tried is_submitted().

```py
@app.route("/login", methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        return "in if"
    else:
        return "in else"
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

```html
 <body>
  <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
          <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Login</h1>
          <form class="form-group">
            {{ form.username.label(class="form-control") }}
            {{ form.username(class="form-control") }}
          </form>
          <form class="form-group">
            {{ form.password.label(class="form-control") }}
            {{ form.password(class="form-control") }}
          </form>
          <div class="checkbox mb-3">
      </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
          </div>
     </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

```py
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                        validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = StringField('Password',
                           validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

right now when i'm entering localhost:5000/login it redirects me instantly to site with "in else" statement i want submit form after i've put some data to it

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code into `if request.method == 'POST'`:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       if form.is_submitted():
          return "in if"
       else:
          return "in else"
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```